# Unity instantiate prefab and get components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying out a unity tutorial and the section of getting the prefab components gives me an error of `The type arguments for method GameObject.GetComponent<T>() cannot be inferred from usage.`

```
GameObject newAnimal = Instantiate(ListItemPrefab) as GameObject;
ListItemController controller = newAnimal.GetComponent();
```

The tutorial website is https://www.folio3.com/blog/creating-dynamic-scrollable-lists-with-new-unity-canvas-ui/

I have search for examples but have found nothing.

Comment: That tutorial is wrong. [`GetComponent` requires a Type parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: I was thinking that but I am unsure what type because there is multiple components of image and text that are children of the prefab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing really difficult about this. You just have to use:

```cs
T componentReference = gameObjectReference.GetComponent<T>();
```

where T is the type of component you want to get a reference to.
So, in your case, you should use:

```
ListItemController controller = newAnimal.GetComponent<ListItemController>();
```

You may want to study a little bit the C# Generics: [Microsoft's Introduction to Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/introduction-to-generics)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type parameter for the get component method.

```
ListItemController controller = newAnimal.GetComponent<ListItemController>();
```